# Why does my trigger throw ORA-01747?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am sending startdate value to end date, createdby value to modifiedby and so on specified in code. This operation should be performed only during update information. But I get

> ORA-01747 : "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification error" in toad

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SMTS.SMTS_DR_TIMINGS_UPDATE_RECORD
BEFORE UPDATE OF START_DATE
ON SMTS.SMTS_DR_TIMINGS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tmpvar NUMBER;

BEGIN

  BEGIN
      update SMTS_DR_TIMINGS 
      set END_DATE = :new.START_DATE, 
          MODIFIED_BY = :new.CREATED_BY, 
          MODIFIED_DATETIME = :new.CREATED_DATETIME
      where TOWNSHIP_CODE = :new.TOWNSHIP_CODE 
      and  DR_ID = :new.DR_ID 
      and END_DATE is null ;

      Exception
      when others then null;

  END;       

END SMTS_DR_TIMINGS_UPDATE_RECORD;
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanx in advance

Comment: Is this your whole code?

Comment: You can't update the same table in a FOR EACH ROW trigger. You should consider putting this logic into an AFTER UPDATE trigger at the statement level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER smts.smts_dr_timings_update_record
   BEFORE UPDATE OF start_date
   ON smts.smts_dr_timings
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   tmpvar   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      IF UPDATING ('start_date') AND <your logic> THEN 
      :new.end_date := :new.start_date;
      :new.modified_by := :new.created_by;
      :new.modified_datetime := SYSDATE;
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         NULL;
   END;
END smts_dr_timings_update_record;
```

**Update 1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trg
   BEFORE UPDATE OF my_col
   ON my_table
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   tmpvar   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      IF UPDATING ('my_col')
      THEN
         :new.creation_date := SYSDATE;
         :new.last_update_date := SYSDATE;
         :new.last_updated_by := 1234;
      END IF;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         NULL;
   END;
END test_trg;
```

Update statement

```
update my_table set my_col='Test update' where my_primary_key= 45;
```

The above works fine.

Comment: I cannot use this because i want to update on particular row not on all rows.Please suggest for single row

Comment: @keval You can wrap the trigger code with your condition to check the primary key of your table.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You mean to say it is updating all the rows or not updating the rows

Comment: BEGIN
    
       If updating('START_DATE') AND TOWNSHIP_CODE = :new.TOWNSHIP_CODE and  DR_ID = :new.DR_ID and END_DATE is null 
        THEN 
       :new.end_date := :new.start_date;
      :new.modified_by := :new.created_by;
      :new.modified_datetime := SYSDATE;
       END IF;
        Exception
        when others then null;                     It says me to declare townshipcode

Comment: I added new before township_code, dr_id and enddate error was gone but during update this error was thrown

Comment: ORA-04091: table SMTS.SMTS_DR_TIMINGS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SMTS.SMTS_DR_TIMINGS_UPDATE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SMTS.SMTS_DR_TIMINGS_UPDATE'

Comment: @keval I have updated my answer, I did not get mutating error. Only one row is updated with my trigger.